# crontab run every 15 minutes starting at minute 00:30 after midnight

Tags: unix, cron, cronexpression

Is it possible to define a cron entry to run every 15 minutes, but the first run should start at 30 minutes past midnight.

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier to use the following crontab entry with a wrapper script that skips the run if the current time is before 30 minutes past midnight.

```
*/15 * * * * your_wrapper_script.sh
```

Another option is to split the cronjob into 2 entries:

```
30,45 0 * * * your_original_cron_job
*/15 1-23 * * * your_original_cron_job
```

Comment: Thanks @Alwin, it feels like crontab needs feature improvements. +1 for your answer.